# Cambiar tamaño columna grid con evento mouseover

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, xaml

estoy intentando crear una animación con cambiar el tamaño de una columna de un Grid al pasar el ratón por encima. No sé si quiera si eso se puede hacer. O hay que meter un objeto dentro como un Stackpanel y poner el trigger IsMouseOver sobre él. También tengo que cambiar el tamaño pero solo por el lado derecho, osea, es como si se mostrase y ocultase un panel al lado izquierdo. Me he dado cuenta que al cambiar el tamaño de la columna se encoje y agrande por los dos lados. Quizá hay que hacerlo con otro control? No tiene que ser un grid por narices, solo quiero un panel con botonoes a la izquierda que mostrar y ocultar. Alguna idea? 
Ahora tengo esto:

```
         <Grid x:Name="panel1" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Height="916">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Blue">
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=panel1, 
                    Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,-5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
                        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="112" Margin="40,10,0,-3" 
                            Width="193" Style="{StaticResource cambiarTemplate}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Grid.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="100" To="300"
                                                    DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1">

                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="300" To="100"
                                                    DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1">

                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Grid.Triggers>
                </Grid>                
            </Grid>
```

Se parece, pero agrande y encoje por los dos lados de la columna. Es la única idea cutre que se me ha ocurrido.

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: SI se puede, las columnas también pueden llevar un nombre y con ese nombre puedes modificarlo desde código.. ahora no puedo hacer un ejemplo para ponerlo de respuesta pero SI se puede... mas tarde trataré de contestar con un ejemplo.

Comment: Bueno, se trata de hacerlo todo por axml pero si no hay más remedio...Te lo agradeceré

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, ya está hecho. Estaba cometiendo el fallo tonto de no alinear la columna 0 a la izquierda. Si la alineas, el grosor se reduce por la derecha exclusivamente.Gracias de todas formas.